# add child of configurable product in a cart

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, api, addtocart

I want to add child of configurable product in a cart with magento 1 api and my child product is adding in a cart but the problem is its also adding main product like I am adding boots and boots have a child products like (size 6 ,7 ) and I am able to add size wise products but the main product is also adding with each size like if I am adding 6 then first it adds main product then size 6 and in a same cart i am also adding 7 then it adds main product then 7 here is the output of my code

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5654
            [sku] => 56662
            [name] => boots
            [set] => 4
            [type] => configurable
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 422
                )

            [website_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 3618
            [sku] => 56662
            [name] => Boots 6
            [set] => 4
            [type] => simple
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 422
                )

            [website_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5654
            [sku] => 56661
            [name] =>  Boots
            [set] => 4
            [type] => configurable
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 422
                )

            [website_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5390
            [sku] => 56661
            [name] =>  12 
            [set] => 4
            [type] => simple
            [category_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19
                    [1] => 28
                    [2] => 422
                )

            [website_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

and here is the code

```
$arrProducts = array(
                        array(
                            "product_id" => $product_id,
                            "qty" => $qty,
                            "super_attribute" => $options_arr
                        )

                    );
$resultCartProductAdd = $client->call($sessionId,"cart_product.add",array($cart_id,$arrProducts));
                echo json_encode($resultCartProductAdd);
```

thanks

Comment: What is the resultant cart in website when you visit.

Comment: this code is for mobile i am working on api file, so i dont know its showing anything on webpage anyway i have pasted the result of the above code on top ...thanks

Comment: It will add as two products. That is normal you need to show only visible items.

Comment: can you please provide me code how i can only show visible items  is it this code   $cartItems = $cart-id->getAllVisibleItems();

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
$collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
foreach($collection as $item){

        if($item->getParentItemId()){
            continue;
        }
        data['productId']=$item->getProductId();
        $data['productName']=$item->getName();
        $data['productSku']=$item->getSku();
        $data['quantity']=$item->getQty();
        $data['itemId']=$item->getId();
  }
```